# Retrieving the username from MembershipUser for a join query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm newer using C#, linq. I'm trying to add the UserName into a query to show it as part of a DataSource of a ListView, I have tested several way to joined, but always I m'receiving next error:

"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Web.Admin.system.User'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

My code is:

```
//Entities

public class Category
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
 }

//class added just for getting the user list  (possibly, I do not need)
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code preparing the filter

```
  //retrieve the data from Order and Category
  IQueryable<Order> orders = orderService.GetAllOrders();
  IQueryable<Category> category = categoryService.GetAllCategories();
  //obtain the users
  MembershipUserCollection members = Membership.GetAllUsers();

  // 1st option for managing users directly with memberShip variable
  var memberShip = members.Cast<MembershipUser>().ToDictionary(m => m.ProviderUserKey, m => m.UserName).AsQueryable();

  // 2nd option, I have added this code to see if I could manage the users as a list
  List<User> users = new List<User>();
  foreach (var _member in memberShip)
        {
            users.Add(new User { Id = (Guid)_member.Key, Name = _member.Value });
        }

  //Getting information to fill a listview
        var DDLsource = from i in orders
                        join c in category on i.CategoryId equals c.Id
                        join u in users on i.UserId equals u.Id // 1st I tried to use memberShip directly but gave me error of types
                        select new
                        {
                            i.Id,
                            i.Description,
                            CategoryName = c.Name,
                            UserName = u.Name
                        };
        ListViewOrders.DataSource = DDLsource.ToList();
```

Here is where the Error is triggered, I'm trying to understand the error and do other solution, I tested the query like:

Example 2

```
        var DDLsource = from i in orders
                        join c in category on i.CategoryId equals c.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            i.Id,
                            i.Description,
                            CategoryName = c.Name,
                            UserName = (from u in users where u.Id == i.UserId select u.Name)
                        };
```

Example 3

```
        var DDLsource = from i in orders
                        join c in category on i.CategoryId equals c.Id
                        join u in Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>() on i.UserId equals ((Guid)u.ProviderUserKey)
                        select new
                        {
                            i.Id,
                            i.Description,
                            CategoryName = c.Name,
                            UserName = u.UserName
                        };
```

all with the same results, could someone give me a hand with my mistake will surely be very obvious. Thanks in advance

Comment: EF is trying to convert your expression (orders join category) in SQL query but fails when it tries local collection of users

Comment: Thanks for answering. But is there a way that I can transform the local collection as part of the query that I'm trying to execute?.

Comment: I don't think so. Personally, I would cut out join with users from your linq expression and iterate DDLsource (manually or in in new l2o query) to manipulate the rest of the data (UserName).

Comment: That can be a bad news... my intention is to show into a simple ListView, some information of the order and the NAME of those who have added them. Thats why I'm trying to put together all information. When you said cut out do you mean, to separate my query, to insert for each row in the page (in the column of user) a DDL with the user selected?, as a page-level selection.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this (sorry, untested code...):

```
var DDLsource = 
  from i in orders
  join c in category on i.CategoryId equals c.Id
  select new
  {
    i.Id,
    i.Description,
    CategoryName = c.Name,
    i.UserId,
    UserName = ""
  };

foreach(var ddl1 in DDLsource)
  ddl1.UserName = Membership.GetUser(ddl1.UserId).Name;
```

Comment: I got your idea and sounds reasonable, but when I try to run the app, I get the message: "property or indexer "AnonymousType#2.UserName" cannot be assigned to - its read only

Comment: I already found several documentation where you cannot use an anonomous types with linq to sql when you want to update a record. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d87c0a2-e0b7-4f34-b74d-863df636fcae/problem-updating-linq-results-with-anonymoustyperead-only        or      http://forums.asp.net/t/1323970.aspx/1   or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755413/modify-linq-output-anonymoustype-cannot-be-assigned  <<<<   seems that I have to find another way to do it. >>>>

Comment: Sorry, told you it was untested. Should have created a class for the intermediate result. Or materialize first set in memory and then linq-join to a second set. There are surely few options. I'll correct the code later, now I have to hurry...